# Rails and Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I follow this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) (except I put gem 'jquery-rails' in my gemfile ).

The problem, if I click to new post, and fill the form and click to create -> ajax don't work, and show method showing the simple post.

my create.js.erb:

```
$('body').html("<h1><%= escape_javascript(@post.title) %></h1>").append("<%= escape_javascript(@post.content) %>");
```

create method

```
def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'asdasd') }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.js
  end
end
```

end

_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@post, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're replacing the entire body of your page with the contents

```
<h1><%= escape_javascript(@post.title) %></h1>
```

You probably want to append it to some kind of place holder like so

```
$('#postlist').append('a bunch of html')
```

Check out the DOM manipulation methods [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Comment: if I use $('#showme').html("<h1><%= escape_javascript(@post.title) %></h1>").append("<%= escape_javascript(@post.content) %>");

and I put <div id="showme"></div> in the application.html.erb, nothing changed

Comment: @Dodi, so you ran `rails generate jquery:install` as well? Can you also post the code where you create the html form?

Comment: yes, I ran rails generate jquery:install, I edited the questson

Comment: @Dodi, everything looks correct to me. Can you verify that you have rails.js and jquery.js in your public/javascripts folder? Do you see any javascript errors before the page reloads?

Comment: lol, the rails.js was the original, the jquery:install do not rewrited, I deleted rails.js and recall jquery:install, now its work! thanks for the help